# Ace Overflow - Google Chrome extension that replaces WMD Editor with Ace on all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: script

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Ace Overflow]

### About

Ace Overflow is a Google Chrome extension that replaces WMD Editor with [Ace](http://ace.c9.io) on all Stack Exchange sites.
The reason I created it because I found it hard to write quick answers that included some code without copy pasting between the editor and an IDE.
The way it works is kinda.. tricky. As Ace does not support converting a textarea into an editor I had to
create a link between the two. WMD textarea is still on the page, but hidden, everything is proxied into it.

#### License

MIT

#### Download

Currently the extension is only available from [github](https://github.com/bagonyi/aceoverflow). Download the crx and drop it onto the `chrome://extensions/` page. You need to be logged in to see the Ace editor.

**Please note that the extension is at an early stage, thus might have (it has -> undo / redo) some bugs. If you are writing a lengthy answer make sure to save it to the clipboard first! I am not responsible for lost questions / answers.**

#### Platform

Google Chrome

### Contact

[David Bagonyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637552/bagonyi)

### Code

Code is hosted on [github](https://github.com/bagonyi/aceoverflow).

**Suggestions, pull requests are welcome!**

Comment: This should be the default! Looks great, seems to be a bug with resizing the textarea though.